# Finding the values of $k$ for which $3\sin(\theta)+k\cos(\theta+30^\circ)=7$ has real solutions

Tags: trigonometry

> Find the values of $k$ for which this equation has real solutions.
> $$3\sin\left(\theta \right)+k\cos\left(\theta +30^\circ\right)=7$$

I wrote the LHS into $a\ \sin\left(\theta\right)+b\cos\left(\theta\right)$ :
$$\left(3-\frac{k}{2}\right)\sin\left(\theta\right)+\frac{\sqrt{3}}{2}k\cos\left(\theta\right)$$

I need to verify that this is correct and find how to proceed from here onwards.

Comment: Cf. [Sine and cosine](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/List_of_trigonometric_identities#Sine_and_cosine) linear combination formula.

Comment: Use the tangent half-angle substitution

Answer (score 1):

The moment you come up with this equation,
$$(3-\frac{k}{2})\sin\theta+\frac{\sqrt{3}}{2}k\cos\theta=7$$
One must look at the RHS. It is 7 (which is kind of big for terms involving $a\sin\theta+b\cos\theta$

Find the maximum value of the LHS! You will get a quadratic in k.

I recommend that you try it on your own once and then look at this solution.
Use the inequality,
$$a\sin\theta+b\cos\theta\le\sqrt{a^{2}+b^{2}}$$

Further, write
$$7\le\sqrt{(3-\frac{k}{2})^{2}+\frac{3k^{2}}{4}}$$
$$7\le\sqrt{9+\frac{k^{2}}{4}-3k+\frac{3k^{2}}{4}}$$
$$49\le k^{2}-3k+9$$
$$k^{2}-3k-40\ge0$$
$$(k-8)(k+5)$$
$$k\ge8\ or\ k\le-5$$

**Proof of the inequality,**
$$a\sin\theta+b\cos\theta\le\sqrt{a^{2}+b^{2}}$$

start with assigning,
$$a\sin\theta+b\cos\theta=k$$
On squaring, we get,
$$a^{2}\sin^{2}\theta+b^{2}\cos^{2}\theta+2ab\ \sin\theta\cos\theta=k^{2}$$
Divide by $\cos^{2}\theta$
$$a^{2}\tan^{2}\theta+b^{2}+2ab\ \tan\theta=k^{2}\sec^{2}\theta$$
Now, on using $\sec^{2}\theta=1+\tan^{2}\theta$ and rearranging, we get
$$\left(a^{2}-k^{2}\right)\tan^{2}\theta+2ab\ \tan\theta+b^{2}-k^{2}=0$$
Thus, we get a quadratic in $\tan\theta$. For it to have real roots, the Discriminant (D) of the equation must be greater than or equal to zero.
(Where, for a general quadratic $px^{2}+qx+r=0$, $D=q^{2}-4pr$)
Therefore,
$$D\ge0$$
$$4a^{2}b^{2}-4\left(a^{2}-k^{2}\right)\left(b^{2}-k^{2}\right)\ge0$$
On slight rearrangement, we get
$$k^{4}\le k^{2}\left(a^{2}+b^{2}\right)$$
for $k\ne0$,
$$k\le\sqrt{a^{2}+b^{2}}$$
Resubstituting,
$$a\sin\theta+b\cos\theta\le\sqrt{a^{2}+b^{2}}$$
Hence Proved.

Comment: how did u come up with this inequality? is it a standard result?

Comment: Yes, it is a standard result. Its proof is similar to the previous answer given by @Angae MT but I have mentioned it in my answer for sake of completion.